# Default starting values for; start, etastart and mustart when fitting GAM

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

I am trying to understand how the GAM model works. I understand the optimization process and the leave one out process of developing the spline, but I do not know what R (or potentially all ways of fitting GAM) uses for the starting values; mustart, etastart and start.

I looked at the glm.fit code and it appears that the family and link function used in the gam model are used in finding these starting values but trying to reverse engineer an answer has been quite frustrating. Was wondering if there is a better way to find out what these values are.

Comment: You should specify the package you are using: my guess is `gam` (rather than `mgcv`, `GAMboost`, or any of the other GAM-fitting packages).

Comment: There's probably no better way to find the values than digging into the code. Looking at the [`gam.fit` code as you suggest](https://github.com/cran/gam/blob/master/R/gam.fit.R) make it look like they evaluate `family$initialize`. The code shown with `gaussian()$initialize`, `binomial()$initialize` seems pretty short - looks like `mustart` is usually `y` for Gaussian and `(n * y + 0.5) / (n + 1)` for binomial in most cases - depending on your data structure and weights.

Comment: That it what I thought the code looked like. I must admit I have used GAM for a while without truly knowing how it fits splines, just trying to fully understand what is going on in background, have a lot of self doubt. So then etastart seems to be family$linkfun(mustart), which would imply it is just y*identity (as that is the Gaussian link)?

Comment: Looks like it. If you want to learn more about GAM, [Simon Wood's book is a must-read](http://a.co/6s4hZRy) (and I'd recommend using his `mgcv` package rather than the `gam` package).